# Unable to edit hosts file with python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, hosts

I am trying to write a python script which can block websites based on the time of the day but i am not able to edit the hosts file in windows even running the cmd as an administrator.
Here's the Code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt 
hosts_location=r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
hosts_temp="hosts"
blocked_websites=['www.facebook.com','facebook.com']
redirect="127.0.0.1"

while True:
   if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,8) < dt.now() < 
   dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,17):
    with open(hosts_location,"r+") as file:
        content=file.read()
        for website in blocked_websites:
            if website in content:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(redirect+"\t"+website+"\n")
    print("Working Hours....")
else:
    with open(hosts_location,"r+") as file:
        content=file.readlines()
        file.seek(0)
        for line in content:
            if not any(website in line for website in blocked_websites):
                file.write(line)
        file.truncate()
    print("Fun Time...")
time.sleep(5)
```

Update:The code is working fine for a local hosts file but when i try it for the real hosts file even as administrator the script just flashes and with cmd shows message "[Errno 13]:Permission Denied".
Also i am not able to edit hosts even with notepad even as adminstrator my os is windows 10 home edition 64-bit.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: And what's with all the `dt.now().something` calls?

Comment: Your indentation is off as well. After `while True:` everything should be indented it's possible that's what's causing your problem

Comment: I didn't run this exact code (because I don't want my hosts file to be completely destroyed), but I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you should elaborate on why you think you can't modify the file (Does anything throw an exception?).

Comment: I get this error even running cmd as administrator:              
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
If you are not an administrator, change permissions of the hosts file by *right clicking--> Properties --> Security* and allow Read/Write/Execute Permissions for **Users**.
Then **open Command Prompt as administrator** and run the script. It will work!

Answer (score 0):

try to save the python file as a .pyw extension
This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the hosts file and uncheck "read only" then go to security tab and give the permissions to user to read and write. Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change access to file from users.
Go to **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** and click right on **properties**, choose **security** and edit access to file.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just change the path to be:

```
hosts_location = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"
```

without r", and it will work