# "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a web blocker by writing to the hosts file in system32, and i'm getting the error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'`. I have a flask server running.
Here's my code.

```py
hostsPath=r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
while True:
  with open(hostsPath,'r+') as file:
    content=file.read()
    for site in websites:
      if site in content:
        pass
      else:
        file.write(redirect+" "+site+"\n")
```

I've tried restarting my pc, changing enviroment variables and running my script as admin, and nothing seems to work.

Edit: No the permissions is not on read-only

Comment: Did you change the permissions on the host file? Might be marked as read only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758809/unable-to-edit-hosts-file-with-python

Comment: as I remeber some Antiviruses may set it `"read-only"` for security reason and you have to change to `"read-write"` before writing. In Windows console you could use `attrib -r C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. And later you can use `+r` instead of `-r` to set it back `"read-only"`

Comment: you can use `not` to write it without `pass` - `if site not in content: file.write(...)`